# Trigger method without change route location backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, history.js

I have an issue with backbone.js `history`.

When an user click on a link, I stop the propagation and I would like to call the method matching with the href without changing the location.

```
$(document).on("click", "a[href^='/']", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  Router.goToIntraRoute($(event.target).attr("href"));
});
```

In the backbone `router` :

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "user/:id": "openProfile"
  },

  // Changes the location
  modifyRoute: function(route){
    this.navigate(route, {trigger: true, replace: false});
  },

  // Doesn't change the location
  goToIntraRoute: function(route){
    // URL modified
    this.navigate(route, {trigger: false, replace: false});
  }
});
```

I would like the method goToIntraRoute doesn't modify my url but trigger the method... Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you don't want the new "page" to appear in the history, you could just call the route handler directly. To get you started, here's a simplified example:

```
goToIntraRoute: function(route){
    if (this.routes[route]) {
        this.routes[route]();
    }
}
```

To actually use that fragment, you'll need to manage the context (`this`) appropriately. Also, if your routes include wildcards or regular expressions, then you'll have to explicitly parse those from the parameters since you won't be relying on the router.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It's a good idea if I can't make it more cleaner. The `routes` array is a little bit more complicated because the route that I send like `/user/2` is not the same `user/:id`. If I find the script to make the matching like backbone, it might work !